# Qual é a maneira correta de se obter a data do dispositivo?

Tags: java, android

Essa é uma questão relativamente simples, mas que tem quebrado muito minha cabeça. Preciso pegar a data e hora em um determinado momento da execução de meu aplicativo, mas não sei qual é a maneira mais recomendada de se fazer isso. Em alguns lugares, vi sugerirem usar a API `Time`, em outros me disseram pra usar o `Calendar`, outros me disseram pra usar o `Date`, uns me indicaram pra formatar a saída usando `SimpleDateFormat`, outros disseram que o `SimpleDateFormat` pode apresentar problemas de performance e me falaram pra usar o `DateFormat`... enfim, estou perdido. Não sei por onde começar. Nessa situação, qual é o caminho mais indicado?

Comment: Depende do que você pretende fazer **:)**

Comment: Quero apenas pegar a data de maneira simples e que seja eficiente. Como vi várias opiniões diferentes, códigos diferentes, fiquei confuso. A ideia é pegar a data e armazenar em uma String, e em outra String armazenar a hora.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` é o mais eficiente se a tua principal preocupação é performance. `Date()` deve estar perto em termos de performance, pois trata-se de apenas um encapsulador de um um valor (long) em milésimos de segundo.

A classe `Calendar` é, comparativamente, mais lenta e bastante mais complexa que resulta da necessidade de lidar com todas caracteristicas inerentes à representação da data e hora (anos bissextos, ajustes para horário de verão/inverno, diferentes zonas horárias, etc).

Em conclusão:

- se a principal preocupação é a performance então sugeria
  System.currentTimeMillis()`.
- Para efectuar cálculos ou formatar datas para o utilizador sugeriria
  o uso da classe [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) devido à sua flexibilidade. Possui um
  método `getInstance` que retorna uma implementação de acordo com as
  definições regionais (região/localização geográfica) do dispositivo.
  Por exemplo, se o dispositivo estiver configurado para uma
  localização na Europa ou América irá devolver um calendário
  Gregoriano.

  A sua utilização é simples:

  > ```
  > Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
  > Date data = c.getTime();
  > ```

  O método `getInstance` devolve um 'calendário' inicializado com a
  data e hora actuais de acordo com as definições locais do
  dispositivo.

Finalmente, a classe [Time](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) está declarada como obsoleta desde a API Level 22 e já anteriormente, a própria página da API, avisava contra o seu uso devido a vários problemas que haviam sido detectados e recomendava o uso da classe Calendar ou GregorianCalendar.

> This class has a number of issues and it is recommended that
>   GregorianCalendar is used instead.

Comment: No caso, se eu apenas quiser pegar a data atual de forma simples, uso o Calendar? Queria algo fácil de formatar, ou que já viesse formatado. Devo usar o SimpleDateFormat então? Performance não é um problema, foi apenas o que vi dizerem por aí, a não ser que a diferença seja absurda.

Answer (score 1):

Na prática utiliza todas estas classes, neste exemplo gera duas strings dia e hora, com o formato para dia 02-03-2018 e string hora 22:21:30

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();//cria o obj calendar e atribui a hora e data do sistema
    Date data = calendar.getTime();//transforma o obj calendar em obj Date

    SimpleDateFormat sddia = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");//cria um obj de formatação de data
    SimpleDateFormat sdhora = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");//cria um obj de formatação de hora
    String dia = sddia.format(data);//gera a string final formatada no estilo "dd-MM-yyyy"
    String hora = sdhora.format(data);//gera a string final formatada no estilo "HH:mm:ss"
```